# Error: Could not create Java Virtual Machin

Tags: java

I keep trying to run my index.html file in my dynamic web project in eclipse and this happens as shown in the image below. I'm new with this stuff so please forgive if I can't provide further details
[image]

Comment: is there java code related to this and could you paste it into the post? Otherwise you should tag with the application you are using or html if it's an html error

Answer (score 0):

The version of Tomcat you are using is not working with the version of Java you are using.

Either upgrade Tomcat or get an older version of Java and tell Eclipse about it.